# decode-jpeg2000.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at decode-jpeg2000.js:15

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I am using the following dicom view

https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv-jqui

while i am trying to upload some dicom, i will got the following error

"decode-jpeg2000.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at decode-jpeg2000.js:15"[image]

Comment: What is there in line 15 of `decode-jpeg2000.js`? It is probably trying to access an object which is `undefined` due to some reason

Comment: var res = decoder.tiles[0].items;

Comment: This means, the `decoder` object does not have a `tiles` property.

Comment: Could you share the data that triggers the error? Not sure if this is the appropriate place to discuss this, you can also open an issue on the dwv project.